# Regex for Active Directory password

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-match

Been trying all morning to figure out a regex pattern for an AD password restriction we're trying to enforce. Any ideas?

- MUST have at least one lower case character ( a-z )
- MUST have at least one upper case character ( A-Z )
- MUST have at least one numerical character ( 0-9 )
- MUST have at least one of the following special characters, but must be able to permit all:
  ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) - _ + = { } [ ] | \ : ; " ' < > , . ? /
- 8 to 14 characters long

Can be in ANY order

I've tried about 50 combinations and the special characters part eludes me.

The one's I've found on here or online don't include the bracket special characters and a few others unfortunately.

Comment: regex for this is long and evil... It is easier to break it up into multiple checks and then come back with 'Unacceptable password, MUST have at least one lower case character' or 'Unacceptable password,MUST have at least one numerical character ( 0-9 )'

Also, try this and see if this works : **(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$**

Comment: I'm VERY stuck on the special character part I can handle every other besides that

Comment: @siam what do you mean? For what I need? They're generic passwords that can literally be whatever as long as they contain one of every of the above possibilities

Comment: @chris85 that's how our team set it up I don't have control over what's in it only front end

Comment: I think that decreases security. You can modify the `{8,}` on the dup and it would be able to accommodate that, I think.

Comment: @chris85 I put it in those because it's used a lot in both and more eyes versus just putting it in one area, it relates to all.  It's also not my call it's how active directory PW are set up here.

Comment: No..it leaves off certain characters I need like : ; <> {}

Comment: You updated the character class to include your allowed characters? Use the `@`.

Comment: Yes it's still failing on all the regex testers with my test cases

Comment: Provide an example that should work and doesnt. Use the `@` for tagging here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple **seperate** lookaheads from the start of string should work ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/lD1Q0S/5))

`^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#!@$%^&*()\-_+={}[\]|\\:;"'<>,.?\/]).{8,14}$`

```
^                                              # anchors to start of string
(?=.*?[a-z])                                   # lookahead for lowercase
(?=.*?[A-Z])                                   # lookahead for uppercase
(?=.*?[0-9])                                   # lookahead for numbers
(?=.*?[#!@$%^&*()\-_+={}[\\]|\:;"'<>,.?\/])    # lookahead for special characters
.{8,14}                                        # the actual capture, also sets boundaries for 8-14
$                                              # anchors to end of string
```

**Updated to include !, and @. Missed them in first test.**

Updated to escape hyphen.